# Requests from this iOS client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked

Tags: ios, swift

Getting this error when i updated my project swift version 4 to 5.Check many post related to this error but not able fix that.

```
 "message": "Requests from this iOS client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "Requests from this iOS client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden"
  }
],
```

Comment: Same issue, Google-info.plist files seem to be fine, same id, all bundle-id's added and I still can't make a request and not get 403 in my face. That is so frustrating.

Comment: i have update from swift 4.2 to 5 that's why getting this error. This is header issue. now it is fixed

Comment: Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue was the firebase updated version/SDK. It doesn’t cast [String: Any] to HTTPHeaders and always fails.

```
let requestURL = URL(string: urlString)!
        let encoding: ParameterEncoding = (method == .get ? URLEncoding.default : JSONEncoding.default)
        var _headers: HTTPHeaders = HTTPHeaders()
        //  Convert header dictionary to HTTPHeaders
        if let headers = headers { for key in headers.keys { if let value = headers[key] as? String { _headers.add(name: key, value: value) }}}
        let request = alamofireManager.request(requestURL,
                                               method: method,
                                               parameters: parameters,
                                               encoding: encoding,
                                               headers: headers as? HTTPHeaders)
                                               headers: _headers)
        request
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<500) //range of acceptable status code for the response success
            .responseData(completionHandler: { response in
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.

```
" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The server responded with an error: 
 - URL: https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<app-name>/installations/ 
 - HTTP status code: 403 
 - Response body: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from this iOS client application <bundle-id> are blocked.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_IOS_APP_BLOCKED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "consumer": "projects/",
          "service": "firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: have you updated your swift version

Comment: you should check your google plist bundle id first. is it same as your project

Comment: Solved. Just added these files back into the project.